# .NET MAUI Restore Picker values from database data

Tags: mvvm, maui

I am new to MVVM. I am loading data from the database in my ViewModel via a ContentPage behavior - an EventToCommand behavior for the Appearing event. I need to use the data to restore values in dropdowns (Pickers) on the page. However, the codebehind OnAppearing code gets called before the ViewModel Appearing code, which means I don't have access to the data in the codebehind, and I don't have access to the dropdowns in the ViewModel.

How should I be doing this?

Update with some of the code in question:

In my ContentPage, I have these behaviors:

```
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding DisappearingCommand}" EventName="Disappearing" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

In my ViewModel, I implement the AppearingCommand:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task Appearing()
{
    try
    {
        DataModel = new Model.Core.JobEntryModel();
        await DataModel.Load(this.PageParameters);
        this.LoadFromModel(DataModel);
        ...
```

The above loads data from the database and moves it where it needs to be. (ViewModel properties are set in LoadFromModel).

Here is the code for one of the Pickers:

```
<Picker x:Name="GuaranteePicker"                                   
    SelectedIndexChanged="GuaranteePicker_SelectedIndexChanged"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GuaranteeOptionsList}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Guarantee}">
</Picker>
```

Here is the GuaranteeOptionsList:

```
[ObservableProperty]
public List<GuaranteeModel> guaranteeOptionsList;
```

GuaranteeModel is a class with some properties, and the Guarantee field is the value to display.

The SelectedIndexChanged code checks the selection, and controls the visibility of other items.

The data that is saved is only a string. I have to identify which object in the GuaranteeOptionsList is the one that matches the saved data.So, in the ViewModel, I implement the OnGuaranteeChanged function in order to do that, and set the SelectedIndex on the picker. But I don't have access to the picker there...

I'm not sure this code has helped, but it gives a little bit of context. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE 2:

The options list is loaded directly from the database:

```
        AsyncTableQuery<GuaranteeModel> guaranteeQuery = db.Table<GuaranteeModel>().Where(x => x.ResCom == Constants.kGuaranteeTypeNew);
        dbGuarantees = await guaranteeQuery.ToListAsync();
```

I copy that result into the GuaranteeOptionsList, which is an ObservableProperty on the ViewModel.

Yet Another Update in response to comments:

@JessieZhang - I can't post the whole thing currently for business reasons, but I will make a separate page that demonstrates the situation.

@SirRufo - Currently I have changed the List to ObservableCollection while trying Jason's suggestion. The Model is loaded from the database, and the ViewModel properties are loaded from the model. The data is copied and set to the ViewModel property like this:

```
GuaranteeOptionsList = new ObservableCollection<GuaranteeModel>(model.dbGuarantees);
```

I'm still unclear if people are saying that the binding/observablecollection should be able to set the picker value based on the saved string, when the picker is showing a list of objects, and displaying that string property - or, if I still have to look up the saved string and set the selection myself. I do begin to see though that I might be thinking about this backwards - even though I don't have access to the Picker directly in the ViewModel, I can bind it to a separate property that gets set when I do determine the selection. I will update the question with the standalone example as time allows today.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  Data binding should take care of this for you if you use it correctly

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added some code and explanation to the question.

Comment: It would help to see how you add data to the list, but more than likely using an ObservableCollection instead of a List will fix it

Comment: I added info about loading the list, but I will switch to ObservableCollection and see what happens.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your viewmodel and `yourpage.xaml` file and `yourpage.xaml.cs` ?

Comment: post the code where you set a value to `GuaranteeOptionsList` and I guess you set the value to the field and not the property which make a huge difference here (notification) - FYI you can bind `SelectedIndex` property to an `int` property of your viewmodel